# Ionic function return value in object t and value stored in __zone_symbol__value:

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

in following code, I want to return the value but it returns object:

**code :**

```
console.log(count(id));

count(id,url){

    return new Promise(resolve =>
      this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data.count);// it shows 3 and is correct 
          resolve(data.count);
        }));
  }
```

**output** of `console.log(count(id));` is:

```
{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state:true
__zone_symbol__value:3
```

Comment: You cannot return the value that has not yet been fetched. Returning the promise for the value is fine.

Comment: @Bergi thanks. could you please guide me more? what should I do now?

Comment: Just call it as `count(id).then(console.log)` instead. The implementation is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is an object that represents the eventual completion or failure of an operation.

It does not return the value of the function right away, it will return the value when `resolve` is called.

So in the following example:

```
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(100), ms);
  });
}
```

If you do `console.log(wait(1000));` it will log the `Promise`, the object that the function is returning. To get the value you want you have to wait for the `Promise` to execute, you can do that in two ways:

Modern JavaScript (`async/await`)

```
const result = await wait(1000);
console.log(result); // 100
```

Using `then`

```
wait(1000).then((result) => console.log(result));
```

See also

- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: `count(post.id).then(count => {
   this.count = count;
});` this code was helpfull.